# Why does fluid (water) stick to the top of an obstacle?

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation

In our simulation, Fluid (water) drops on an obstacle and splashes. It mostly works fine, but there is noticeable part which *remains on top of the obstacle*! In reality, there should be no water there, as you can see the shape of the obstacle is very rounded.

Is there a setting we are missing?

**Our settings:** Obstacle is `no slip`. Fluid is `free slip` (which, it was assumed, forces water not to stick to obstacle). Water. Baking resolution is `150`.

[image: Animation of water sticking to top of rounded cube]

**See some frames:**

[image: (1) Water above rounded cube (2) Water hitting rounded cube (3) Water stuck to rounded cube]

**Update:**
based on accepted answer:

[image: Animation of water _not_ sticking to rounded cube]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The no-slip for the obstacle is incorrect. No-slip as in not slippery so it is sticky.

From the wiki [page on obstacles](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Fluid/Obstacle) -

- Noslip causes the fluid to stick to the obstacle (zero velocity).
- Free(-slip) allows movement along the obstacle (only zero normal velocity).
- Part(-slip) mixes both types, with 0 being mostly noslip, and 1 being identical to freeslip.

Comment: Thanks for correction. `Free-slip was the key`.